# Momentjs seconds from now till a specific hour

Tags: momentjs

I need to get the number of seconds from now till today with a specific hour.

```
moment().diff(moment().hour(23), 'seconds');
```

The precision is always in hours, I need it to be in seconds.

For example if now is 15:24. I get 28800.

Comment: You might be interested in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674694/how-can-i-format-time-durations-exactly-using-moment-js)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`moment()` is the current time, so if current time is 15:24:32 `moment().hour(23)` returns 23:24:32.  You need to set the minutes and seconds to 0 to get the difference between 15:24:32 and 23:00:00.

This

`moment().diff(moment().hour(23).minute(0).second(0), 'seconds');`

returns -27328 seconds when the current time is 15:24:32

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of Preston's answer...

If you want to return a positive value then you should put the later moment object first. So in this case 
`moment().hour(23).minute(0).second(0).diff(moment(), 'seconds');`

If you're interested in a human readable output, you could also use `to` or `toNow`. Here's an example:
`moment().hour(23).minute(0).second(0).toNow(true);`
will result in `in seconds` or `in 21 hours`

Here's a link to the documentation (which is fantastic):

- diff https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/
- Time `toNow` X https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/tonow/