# Subtract date, month and years dynamically and put data as days using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to subtract a user input years from another input years, but so far I had no luck.

I'll create a `snippet` where you can play.

What I'm trying to do is to make an `input field (A)` to enter years only. Then after that select any date and subtract it from the `input year (A)` (date and month are fixed like 31.03.`input_year`)...

```js
$(document).on('change', '#year_select', function() {
  calculate();
});

$(document).on('change', '#new_date', function() {
  calculate();
});

function calculate() {
  var year_enter = $('#year_select').val();
  var current_year = year_enter+'-03-31';
  var new_date = $('#new_date').val();
  if(year_enter != '') {
    //alert(current_year);
  }
  if(new_date != '') {
    //alert(new_date);
    
    var total = new_date - current_year;
    $('#answer').val(total);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Enter years (A)</p>
<input type="number" id="year_select" min="0" placeholder="Eg: 2018, 2001">

<br>

<p>Select Date (B)</p>
<input type="date" id="new_date">


<p>(A - B)</p>

<input type="text" readonly id="answer">
```

I always get NaN value, my subtract method is incorrect I guess. I tried using `setDate()`, `getDate()` etc, but I don't understand the logic.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Date()` to type cast them into date in order to do arithmetic

```js
$(document).on('change', '#year_select', function() {
  calculate();
});

$(document).on('change', '#new_date', function() {
  calculate();
});

function calculate() {
  var year_enter = $('#year_select').val();
  var current_year = new Date(year_enter + '-03-31');
  var new_date = new Date($('#new_date').val());
  if (year_enter != '') {

  }
  if (new_date != '' && year_enter != '') {

    if (current_year < new_date) {
      $('#answer').val('A must be greater than B');
      return;
    }

    var total = Math.round(Math.abs((current_year.getTime() - new_date.getTime()) / (24*60*60*1000)));

    $('#answer').val(total);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Enter years (A)</p>
<input type="number" id="year_select" min="0" placeholder="Eg: 2018, 2001"><span style="opacity: 0.5;">&nbsp;this currently has fixed -month-day(-03-31) </span>

<br>

<p>Select Date (B)</p>
<input type="date" id="new_date">


<p>(A - B)</p>

<input type="text" readonly id="answer">
```

Comment: Is there any way to subtract exact date, month and years, example 30/05/2018 - 30/05/2017 = 365 days

Comment: I think my topic is incorrect as what I want, sorry for the disturbance... I'll edit

Comment: @Vpa ah ok, i know what you mean - edited my answer. still used `new Date()` in my example to type cast. Also you can see the formula on the snippet for computing days. Hope it helps

Comment: yeah, this is working and very helpful... thank you so much, you saved my days

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be tricky to handle, but the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library makes it a lot easier. In my example I take the input of the two fields, parse them into a moment object and calculate their difference in a duration. You can read more on duration in the [Moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

The code snippet difference is expressed in days. In case you want to change it to months, or years, update the below line.

```
log(Math.round(duration.as('days')) + 'days');
```

You can also include several if statements, to check if the difference is a year, display the result in years. If not, and there's a full month, express the result in months and so on.

Here's a working example in days.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#year_select', function() {
  calculate();
});

$(document).on('change', '#new_date', function() {
  calculate();
});

function calculate() {
  var yearSelect = document.querySelector('#year_select').value;
  var newDate = document.querySelector('#new_date').value;
  var first_date = new window.moment('31-03-' + yearSelect, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  var second_date = new window.moment(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

  if(yearSelect.length !== 4 || newDate === '') {
    log('');
    return;
  }
  
  var duration = window.moment.duration(first_date.diff(second_date));

  log(Math.round(duration.as('days')) + 'days');
}

function log(value) {
  var answer = document.querySelector('#answer');
  answer.value = value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Enter years (A)</p>
<input type="number" id="year_select" min="0" placeholder="Eg: 2018, 2001">

<br>

<p>Select Date (B)</p>
<input type="date" id="new_date">


<p>(A - B)</p>

<input type="text" readonly id="answer">
```

**NOTE:** There are a few discussions out there on how to format a date/duration, e.g. *1 year, 2 months, 5 days*. Have a look at a possible solution at these discussions if you want something like this.

- [How can I format time durations exactly using Moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674694/how-can-i-format-time-durations-exactly-using-moment-js)
- [How do I use format() on a moment.js duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration)

Comment: How can I achieve the subtract date and month also. Suppose I want to put data as date wise like 09/09/2018 - 08/09/2018 = 1 day etc

Comment: I edit the topic, sorry for the wrong topic... please help me here again

Comment: Hi Vpa, no problem. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, it helps a lot. But I wanna use pure JS here.. thank you so much