# Convert TimeSpan to minutes and seconds in Vue using moment

Tags: vue.js, timespan

The back-end returns me a timespan in the following format as a string:
00:31:07.2764147

I need to interpretate that string and return a countdown.

Currently I am using vue 2:

```
  <div v-if="this.time">
  <countdown :time="this.time">
    <p>Time Remaining： {{ this.time.minutes }} minutes, {{ this.time.seconds }} seconds.</p>
  </countdown>
  </div>
```

data () {
return {
time: '00:00.00'
}
}

In my method I have this:

```
        this.time = moment(res.data.resetOtpRetriesTimestamp).format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Currently this returns invalid date.

I have tried to find any documentation but there is nothing there that can translate timespan to minutes and seconds and start a countdown timer which is my goal here.

I do understand that I can parse the string, I was rather looking for some easy moment function or syntax to do it.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I format time durations exactly using Moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674694/how-can-i-format-time-durations-exactly-using-moment-js)

Comment: don't blindly use `moment` directly - they aren't dates.